# How do I run a single test with UnitTest++?

Tags: c++, unittest++

How do I run a single test with UnitTest++ ?

I am running UnitTest++ out of the box as is. My `main` function looks like:

```
int main()
{
   printf("diamond test v0.1 %s\n\n",TIMESTAMP);
   diamond::startup();
   UnitTest::RunAllTests();
   diamond::shutdown();
   printf("press any key to continue...");
   getc(stdin);
}
```

For debugging I would like to write something like `UnitTest::RunSingleTests("MyNewUnitTest");` instead of `UnitTest::RunAllTests();`. Does UnitTest++ provide such a function and if so, what is the syntax?

Comment: You need to tell us more about your environment, what you've tried and failed, etc.

Comment: So you already know how to run two tests then?

Comment: I am running UnitTest++ out of the box as is. My Main function looks like:

int main() {
 
 printf("diamond test v0.1 %s\n\n",__TIMESTAMP__);
 diamond::startup();
 
 UnitTest::RunAllTests();
 
 diamond::shutdown();
 
 printf("press any key to continue...");
 getc(stdin); 
 
}

for debugging I would something like write

 UnitTest::RunSingleTests("MyNewUnitTest");

instead of 

 UnitTest::RunAllTests();

. I wanted to know if there is such a type of function and if yes how the syntax looks like.

Comment: http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/UnitTest++.html Have a read through this, or you tried this and failed !!!!

Comment: hm formatting got broken

Comment: i read the docu, I am using the framework since longer. the point is when first running a test in debug it takes more than a minute already until it is invoked so I want to run just the single test not all suites. I read erverywhere that this is possible wit UnitTest++, but I did not find anything in the docu on how to achieve this.

Comment: Does anybody know how to run a single test/suite with UnitTest++ instead of all tests ? I can debug and read the UnitTest++ code to figure out how this works, I just wanted to skip the effort, since I thought there must be people out there who did this already.

Comment: You should edit your question instead of adding comments. This will be easier for people to answer. Besides, there is no formatting in comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this as your main() for unittest (I actually put this in a file and added that to the unittest library, so that when linking to the library the executable automatically uses this main(). very convenient.)

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  if( argc > 1 )
  {
      //if first arg is "suite", we search for suite names instead of test names
    const bool bSuite = strcmp( "suite", argv[ 1 ] ) == 0;

      //walk list of all tests, add those with a name that
      //matches one of the arguments  to a new TestList
    const TestList& allTests( Test::GetTestList() );
    TestList selectedTests;
    Test* p = allTests.GetHead();
    while( p )
    {
      for( int i = 1 ; i < argc ; ++i )
        if( strcmp( bSuite ? p->m_details.suiteName
                           : p->m_details.testName, argv[ i ] ) == 0 )
          selectedTests.Add( p );
      p = p->next;
    }

      //run selected test(s) only
    TestReporterStdout reporter;
    TestRunner runner( reporter );
    return runner.RunTestsIf( selectedTests, 0, True(), 0 );
  }
  else
  {
    return RunAllTests();
  }
}
```

invoke with arguments to run a single test:

```
> myexe MyTestName
```

or single suite

```
> myexe suite MySuite
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I will give it a try straight away.

Answer (score 7):

This is almost correct. "Test" actually is purposed as a node in a linked list, so when you add it to a new list, you have to correct the pointer to avoid including more tests than you intended.

So you need to replace

```
  p = p->next;
```

with

```
  Test* q = p;
  p = p->next;
  q->next = NULL;
```

Geoffrey

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey!!! This addendum is indeed a must. stijn solution doesn't work without this.

Comment: Doesn't this solution effectively un-link UniTest++ test list. Does UnitTest++ use some other means to clean up?

Answer (score 3):

RunTestsIf can only run one suite if you tell it the name.

```
class MyTrue
{
    public:
        MyTrue(const std::string & suiteName, const std::string & testName)
                : suite(suiteName), test(testName) {}

        bool operator()(const UnitTest::Test* const testCase) const
        {
            return suite.compare(testCase->m_details.suiteName) == 0 && 
                         test.compare(testCase->m_details.testName) == 0;
        }
    private:
        std::string suite;
        std::string test;
};

int main (...) {
    bool isSuite = false;
    std::string suiteName = "suite01";
    std::string testName  = "test01";

    UnitTest::TestReporterStdout reporter;
    UnitTest::TestRunner runner(reporter);
    if (isSuite) {
        runner.RunTestsIf(UnitTest::Test::GetTestList(),
            NULL, MyTrue(suiteName, testName), 0);
    } else {
        runner.RunTestsIf(UnitTest::Test::GetTestList(),
            NULL, UnitTest::True(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This should be documented similar to this in the official documentation of UnitTest++.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using the `predicate` parameter of `RunTestsIf`:

```
TestReporterStdout reporter;
TestRunner runner(reporter);
return runner.RunTestsIf(Test::GetTestList(), "MySuite",
    [](Test* t) { 
        return strcmp(t->m_details.testName, "MyTest") == 0; 
    }, 0);
```

If you do not have suites, or you want to search all of them, you can replace `"MySuite"` with `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @stijn has a bug in the test list manipulation, and therefore it usually runs additional tests that you did not request.

This example uses a predicate functor and also exploits the built-in suite name matching provided by RunTestsIf. It is correct and much simpler.

```
#include "UnitTest++.h"
#include "TestReporterStdout.h"
#include <string.h>
using namespace UnitTest;

/// Predicate that is true for tests with matching name,
/// or all tests if no names were given.
class Predicate
{
public:

Predicate(const char **tests, int nTests)
    : _tests(tests),
      _nTests(nTests)
{
}

bool operator()(Test *test) const
{
    bool match = (_nTests == 0);
    for (int i = 0; !match && i < _nTests; ++i) {
        if (!strcmp(test->m_details.testName, _tests[i])) {
            match = true;
        }
    }
    return match;
}

private:
    const char **_tests;
    int _nTests;
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    const char *suiteName = 0;
    int arg = 1;

    // Optional "suite" arg must be followed by a suite name.
    if (argc >=3 && strcmp("suite", argv[arg]) == 0) {
        suiteName = argv[++arg];
        ++arg;
    } 

    // Construct predicate that matches any tests given on command line.
    Predicate pred(argv + arg, argc - arg);

    // Run tests that match any given suite and tests.
    TestReporterStdout reporter;
    TestRunner runner(reporter);
    return runner.RunTestsIf(Test::GetTestList(), suiteName, pred, 0);
}
```

Comment: I agree - this is a much better way (likely the intended way?) to select tests. Also, the solution above (stjin & Geoffrey) seems to unlink the test list in a way that might not be safe.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the accepted answer is not working for me. When the first test of the suite is loaded into p it just won't jump to the next test (don't know exactly why).

I'm using Xcode and UnitTest++ v1.4

```
#include "UnitTest++.h"
#include "TestReporterStdout.h"

#define SUITE_NAME "ActionFeedback"

using namespace UnitTest;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
#ifdef SUITE_NAME
    TestReporterStdout reporter;
    TestRunner runner( reporter );
    return runner.RunTestsIf( Test::GetTestList() ,  SUITE_NAME , True(), 0 );
#else
    return RunAllTests();
#endif

}
```